# Gradle how to copy all runtime libs including the jars from dependant projects

Tags: gradle

I have a multi module gradle project which is building OK.
Now I want to implement a task that will actually prepare a deliverable package of all built modules together with the all their dependencies and everything else that is needed for running a main class from module-1.jar

In order to achieve this I want to copy all runtime dependencies into a folder together with some environment specific configuration files (properties, XMLs) and then package them up in an archive file.

Say I have this structure:

```
    Root Project
      /      \
 module-1   module-2
```

And module-1 depends on module-2

```
module-1.gradle:

task runModule1 << {
    // Invoke some methods to prepare the module-1 run
    // such as setting module-1 runLocation
    copy {from configurations.runtime into runLocation}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':module-2')
    //... Other thirds party dependencies
}
```

At the end of that copy invocation above all third party dependencies are copied very nicely where I need them. However the module-2.jar is not and wondering why. For sure I can repeat myself and manually copy module-2.jar from the build folder of the module-2 but to me this looks like not the proper way to do it. It has to be a nice gradle solution for this.

Thank you in advance for for your inputs.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *However the module-2.jar is not (...)*?

Comment: And why don't you use `application` plugin?

Comment: Thanks Opal. I addressed the jar name issue

Comment: I changed the question a bit to better reflect what I am trying to achieve. Initially saying I wanted to run the module-1.jar made you suggest the application plugin which was not exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe sounds exactly like what the [Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) provides. It will handle all the dependency copying, etc, for you.

Assuming that `module-1` contains your main class, you add the following to the `module-1` configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "org.stackoverflow.example.MyApp"
```

Since `module-1` has its dependencies towards `module-2` declared correctly, you can now run it like this:

```
gradle module-1:run
:module-2:compileJava
:module-2:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:module-2:classes
:module-1:compileJava
:module-1:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:module-1:classes
:module-1:run
```

Comment: But my question still stands up. Why module-2.jar is not copied as it is a valid runtime dependency?

Comment: I have just realized that application plugin includes the distribution plugin which can be configured to do the extra environment prepare work and then have the specific files put together with the jars. So yes your answer helped solve my problem. Thank you very much. As for nodule-2.jar not being copied across to me looks like a bug.